# Unable to fetch activity of Azure DevOps projects

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using below script to fetch activity of projects in Azure devops. Now the issue is this is working perfectly fine when I give **numOfDays** field as 30, But I want to fetch the activity for last 6 months, if If update **numOfDays** as more than 30..the fields are coming blank even when am sure the projects have activity in last 6 months.

please help me what could be the issue.

```
param (
    [string]$PAT = "",
    [string]$Organization = ""
)

$AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PAT)")) } + @{"Content-Type"="application/json"; "Accept"="application/json"}
$UriOrganization = "https://dev.azure.com/$($Organization)/"
$UriOrganizationRM = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$($Organization)/"

$monthAgo = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-6).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

$uriProject = $UriOrganization + "_apis/projects?`$top=1752&api-version=6.1-preview.4"
$csvFilePath = "new.csv"
$Data = @()

do {
    $ProjectsResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriProject -Method get -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader

    Foreach ($project in $ProjectsResult.value)
    {
        $uriProjectStats = $UriOrganization + "_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery/project/$($project.id)?api-version=6.1-preview.1"   
        $projectStatsBody = @{
            "contributionIds"= @("ms.vss-work-web.work-item-metrics-data-provider-verticals", "ms.vss-code-web.code-metrics-data-provider-verticals", "ms.vss-code-web.build-metrics-data-provider-verticals")
            "dataProviderContext" = @{
                "properties" =@{
                    "numOfDays"=30
                    "sourcePage"=@{
                        "url"=($UriOrganization + $project.name)
                        "routeId"="ms.vss-tfs-web.project-overview-route"
                        "routeValues" =@{
                            "project" = $project.id
                            "controller"="Apps"
                            "action"="ContributedHub"
                            "serviceHost"=$Organization
                            }
                        }          
                    }
                }
            }  | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5

        $projectStatsResult = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uriProjectStats -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader -Method Post -Body $projectStatsBody 
        $projectStatsJson = ConvertFrom-Json $projectStatsResult.Content

        $workItemsCreated = 0
        $workItemsCompleted = 0
        $commitsPushed = 0
        $pullRequestsCreated = 0
        $pullRequestsCompleted = 0

        $workItemsCreated = $projectStatsJson.dataProviders.'ms.vss-work-web.work-item-metrics-data-provider-verticals'.workMetrics.workItemsCreated
        $workItemsCompleted = $projectStatsJson.dataProviders.'ms.vss-work-web.work-item-metrics-data-provider-verticals'.workMetrics.workItemsCompleted
        $commitsPushed = $projectStatsJson.dataProviders.'ms.vss-code-web.code-metrics-data-provider-verticals'.gitmetrics.commitsPushedCount
        if (!$commitsPushed) {$commitsPushed = 0}

        $pullRequestsCreated = $projectStatsJson.dataProviders.'ms.vss-code-web.code-metrics-data-provider-verticals'.gitmetrics.pullRequestsCreatedCount
        if (!$pullRequestsCreated) {$pullRequestsCreated = 0}

        $pullRequestsCompleted = $projectStatsJson.dataProviders.'ms.vss-code-web.code-metrics-data-provider-verticals'.gitmetrics.pullRequestsCompletedCount
        if (!$pullRequestsCompleted) {$pullRequestsCompleted = 0}
               
        $uriBuildMetrics = $UriOrganization + "$($project.id)/_apis/build/Metrics/Daily?minMetricsTime=$($monthAgo)" 
        $buildMetricsResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriBuildMetrics -Method get -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader
        $totalBuilds = 0
        $buildMetricsResult.value | Where-Object {$_.name -eq 'TotalBuilds'} | ForEach-Object { $totalBuilds+= $_.intValue }

        $totalReleases = 0
        $UriReleaseMetrics = $UriOrganizationRM + "$($project.id)/_apis/Release/metrics?minMetricsTime=minMetricsTime=$($monthAgo)"
        $releaseMetricsResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $UriReleaseMetrics -Method get -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader
        $releaseMetricsResult.value | ForEach-Object { $totalReleases+= $_.value }
        
        $repoData = @{
            
            workitemsCreated = $workItemsCreated
            Project = $project.name
            workItemsCompleted = $workItemsCompleted
            commitsPushed = $commitsPushed
            pullRequestsCreated = $pullRequestsCreated
            pullRequestsCompleted = $pullRequestsCompleted
            totalBuilds = $totalBuilds
            totalReleases = $totalReleases
        }
        $Data += New-Object PSObject -Property $repoData
    }
    
    $uriProject = $ProjectsResult.ContinuationToken
} while ($uriProject -ne $null)

# Export the array to a CSV file
$Data | Select-Object  Project, workitemsCreated, workitemsCompleted, commitsPushed, pullRequestsCreated, pullRequestsCompleted, totalBuilds, totalReleases  | Export-Csv -Path $csvFilePath -NoTypeInformation

Write-Host "Data exported to new.csv at $csvFilePath"
```